# upgrade red hat 7 to 8 failed with error "/bin/upgrade: line 19: /sysroot/var/tmp/system-upgrade.state: No such file or directory" in leapp reboot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, boot, upgrade

I'm Troubleshooting an issue. Need help debugging kernel boot or open console to look into journal during boot.

Im running a rhel 7.9 maschine that I'm upgrading to 8.6 with leapp-upgrade tool.
After being promted to reboot, System boots into Upgrade kernel and does its thing.
After some time its stuck and doesnt continue.

gathered log files from the leapp reboot process, I can post more if needed:

```
...

Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: sysinit.target changed dead -> active
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: sysinit.target: Job sysinit.target/start finished, result=done
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Reached target System Initialization.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: basic.target changed dead -> active
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: basic.target: Job basic.target/start finished, result=done
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Reached target Basic System.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: BPF firewalling not supported on this manager, proceeding without.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: sysroot.mount: About to execute: /usr/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/590fdbc8-05cb-4a67-b754-93ca34611494 /sysroot -o ro
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: sysroot.mount: Forked /usr/bin/mount as 1005
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: sysroot.mount: Changed dead -> mounting
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Mounting /sysroot...
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1005]: sysroot.mount: Executing: /usr/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/590fdbc8-05cb-4a67-b754-93ca34611494 /sysroot -o ro
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: ConditionKernelCommandLine=|rd.break=initqueue failed.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: ConditionPathExists=|/lib/dracut/need-initqueue succeeded.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: ConditionPathExists=/usr/lib/initrd-release succeeded.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: BPF firewalling not supported on this manager, proceeding without.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: Passing 0 fds to service
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: About to execute: /bin/dracut-initqueue
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: Forked /bin/dracut-initqueue as 1006
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: Changed dead -> start
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Starting dracut initqueue hook...
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1006]: dracut-initqueue.service: Executing: /bin/dracut-initqueue
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd-udevd[1016]: passed 127 byte device to netlink monitor 0x55b94c876240
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd-udevd[1017]: passed 130 byte device to netlink monitor 0x55b94c8fe0c0
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Got notification message from PID 714 (FDSTORE=1)
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Added fd 39 (n/a) to fd store.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Got notification message from PID 714 (FDSTORE=1)
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Added fd 40 (n/a) to fd store.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Got notification message from PID 714 (FDSTORE=1)
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Added fd 41 (n/a) to fd store.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 1006 (dracut-initqueu).
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Child 1006 (dracut-initqueu) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: Child 1006 belongs to dracut-initqueue.service.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: Changed start -> exited
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: dracut-initqueue.service: Job dracut-initqueue.service/start finished, result=done
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Started dracut initqueue hook.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd-udevd[1018]: passed 127 byte device to netlink monitor 0x55b94c8af050
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Got cgroup empty notification for: /system.slice/dracut-initqueue.service
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Received EPOLLHUP on stored fd 40 (stored), closing.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Received EPOLLHUP on stored fd 41 (stored), closing.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: remote-fs-pre.target changed dead -> active
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: remote-fs-pre.target: Job remote-fs-pre.target/start finished, result=done
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: sysroot.mount: Changed mounting -> mounting-done
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Received SIGCHLD from PID 1005 (mount).
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Child 1005 (mount) died (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: sysroot.mount: Child 1005 belongs to sysroot.mount.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: sysroot.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=0
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: sysroot.mount: Changed mounting-done -> mounted
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: sysroot.mount: Job sysroot.mount/start finished, result=done
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Mounted /sysroot.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Got cgroup empty notification for: /system.slice/sysroot.mount
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Received EPOLLHUP on stored fd 39 (stored), closing.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: upgrade.target changed dead -> active
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: upgrade.target: Job upgrade.target/start finished, result=done
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Reached target System Upgrade.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: BPF firewalling not supported on this manager, proceeding without.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: upgrade.service: Passing 0 fds to service
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: upgrade.service: About to execute: /bin/upgrade
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: upgrade.service: Forked /bin/upgrade as 1022
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: upgrade.service: Changed dead -> start
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Starting System Upgrade...
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1022]: upgrade.service: Executing: /bin/upgrade
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost upgrade[1022]: starting upgrade hook
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost upgrade[1022]: /bin/upgrade: line 19: /sysroot/var/tmp/system-upgrade.state: No such file or directory
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: initrd-root-fs.target: ConditionPathExists=/etc/initrd-release succeeded.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1025]:   WARNING: locking_type (4) is deprecated, using --sysinit --readonly.
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: initrd-root-fs.target changed dead -> active
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1022]: Mounting /usr with -o defaults,ro
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: initrd-root-fs.target: Job initrd-root-fs.target/start finished, result=done
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Found cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd, legacy hierarchy
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_CPU to infinity.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_FSIZE to infinity.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_DATA to infinity.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_STACK to 8388608:infinity.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_CORE to 0:infinity.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_RSS to infinity.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_NPROC to 254679.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_NOFILE to 1024:4096.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_MEMLOCK to 65536.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_AS to infinity.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_LOCKS to infinity.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_SIGPENDING to 254679.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE to 819200.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_NICE to 0.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_RTPRIO to 0.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Setting RLIMIT_RTTIME to infinity.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Spawning container sysroot on /sysroot.
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost upgrade[1042]: Press ^] three times within 1s to kill container.
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost kernel: FAT-fs (sda8): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs (sda9): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1]: Reached target Initrd Root File System.
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Mounting / (MS_REC|MS_SLAVE "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Using legacy hierarchy for container.
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /sysroot on /sysroot (MS_BIND|MS_REC "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Mounting /sysroot (MS_REC|MS_SHARED "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Mounting tmpfs on /sysroot/tmp (MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_STRICTATIME "mode=1777")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Mounting sysfs on /sysroot/sys (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Mounting tmpfs on /sysroot/dev (MS_NOSUID|MS_STRICTATIME "mode=755")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Mounting tmpfs on /sysroot/dev/shm (MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_STRICTATIME "mode=1777")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Mounting tmpfs on /sysroot/run (MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_STRICTATIME "mode=755")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /sys/fs/selinux on /sysroot/sys/fs/selinux (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Remounting /sysroot/sys/fs/selinux (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Mounting devpts on /sysroot/dev/pts (MS_NOSUID|MS_NOEXEC "newinstance,ptmxmode=0666,mode=620,gid=5")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /run/systemd/nspawn/propagate/sysroot on /sysroot/run/systemd/nspawn/incoming (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Remounting /sysroot/run/systemd/nspawn/incoming (MS_RDONLY|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Mounting /sysroot/run/systemd/nspawn/incoming (MS_SLAVE "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /dev/pts/0 on /sysroot/dev/console (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Applying whitelist on architecture: x86
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Applying whitelist on architecture: x32
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Applying whitelist on architecture: x86-64
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Applying NETLINK_AUDIT mask on architecture: x86
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Failed to add audit seccomp rule, ignoring: Invalid argument
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Applying NETLINK_AUDIT mask on architecture: x32
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Applying NETLINK_AUDIT mask on architecture: x86-64
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /dev on /sysroot/dev (MS_BIND|MS_REC "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /dev/mapper on /sysroot/dev/mapper (MS_BIND|MS_REC "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /dev/pts on /sysroot/dev/pts (MS_BIND|MS_REC "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /proc on /sysroot/proc (MS_BIND|MS_REC "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /run/lock on /sysroot/run/lock (MS_BIND|MS_REC "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /run/systemd on /sysroot/run/systemd (MS_BIND|MS_REC "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /run/udev on /sysroot/run/udev (MS_BIND|MS_REC "")...
Dec 14 15:08:54 localhost upgrade[1043]: Bind-mounting /sys on /sysroot/sys (MS_BIND|MS_REC "")...
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost systemd[1]: sysroot-usr.mount: Changed dead -> mounted
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /proc/sys on /proc/sys (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/sys (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /tmp/.#inaccessible892af3a0f1b08168 on /proc/kallsyms (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/kallsyms (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /tmp/.#inaccessible892af3a0f1b08168 on /proc/kcore (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/kcore (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /tmp/.#inaccessible892af3a0f1b08168 on /proc/keys (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/keys (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /tmp/.#inaccessible892af3a0f1b08168 on /proc/sysrq-trigger (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/sysrq-trigger (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /tmp/.#inaccessible892af3a0f1b08168 on /proc/timer_list (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/timer_list (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /proc/acpi on /proc/acpi (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/acpi (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Failed to create directory /proc/apm: No such file or directory
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Failed to create directory /proc/asound: No such file or directory
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /proc/bus on /proc/bus (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/bus (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /proc/fs on /proc/fs (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/fs (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /proc/irq on /proc/irq (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/irq (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /proc/scsi on /proc/scsi (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:57 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/scsi (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Got notification message from PID 714 (FDSTORE=1)
Dec 14 15:09:00 localhost upgrade[1042]: (sd-namespace) succeeded.
Dec 14 15:09:00 localhost upgrade[1042]: Init process invoked as PID 1044
Dec 14 15:09:00 localhost upgrade[1042]: Failed to chown "/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/upgrade.service/payload/cgroup.controllers", ignoring: No such file or directory
Dec 14 15:09:00 localhost upgrade[1042]: Failed to chown "/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/upgrade.service/payload/cgroup.events", ignoring: No such file or directory
Dec 14 15:09:00 localhost upgrade[1042]: Failed to chown "/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/upgrade.service/payload/cgroup.stat", ignoring: No such file or directory
Dec 14 15:09:00 localhost upgrade[1042]: Failed to chown "/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/upgrade.service/payload/cgroup.subtree_control", ignoring: No such file or directory
Dec 14 15:09:00 localhost upgrade[1042]: Failed to chown "/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/upgrade.service/payload/cgroup.threads", ignoring: No such file or directory
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost systemd[1]: systemd-journald.service: Added fd 39 (n/a) to fd store.
Dec 14 15:09:01 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /sys/fs/cgroup (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_STRICTATIME "mode=755")...
Dec 14 15:09:01 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /tmp/.#proc-sys-kernel-random-boot-id3dffa7153841ccda on /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:09:01 localhost upgrade[1044]: Remounting /proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id (MS_RDONLY|MS_NOSUID|MS_NODEV|MS_NOEXEC|MS_REMOUNT|MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:09:01 localhost upgrade[1044]: Bind-mounting /tmp/.#proc-kmsg31eea7d966bf2d6c on /proc/kmsg (MS_BIND "")...
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost systemd[1]: inotify event for /etc/localtime
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to stat /etc/localtime, ignoring: No such file or directory
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost systemd-udevd[1049]: passed 126 byte device to netlink monitor 0x55b94c8fe0c0
Dec 14 15:08:52 localhost systemd-udevd[1050]: passed 127 byte device to netlink monitor 0x55b94c876240
```

I guess the issue is this:

```
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost systemd[1022]: upgrade.service: Executing: /bin/upgrade
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost upgrade[1022]: starting upgrade hook
Dec 14 15:08:51 localhost upgrade[1022]: /bin/upgrade: line 19: /sysroot/var/tmp/system-upgrade.state: No such file or directory
```

how can I debug further? Is there a way to open shell during boot? init=/bin/bash & systemd.unit=emergency.target did not work